# In shipping address i wants shipping rate calculate by City as they default work with Country and postalcode

Tags: magento2

I have to calculate shipping rate by City on shipping address, currently it show shipping rate by postal code and Country update.

I did it on cart page by following tutorial   https://webkul.com/blog/enable-city-field-cart-page-magento2/comment-page-1/?unapproved=17654&moderation-hash=d1044923b0b9b89f10efedb9102fd063#comment-17654

Please help me for same on shipping address.
Thank you

Comment: Anybody knows how can we do ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it, First i make city field as drop-down by layoutprocess.php .
After that magento have API to calculate shipping rate which is **estimate-shipping-methods** . This API run via following path

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

There have method where we can set field name for which we wants to call API.

> checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function (shippingAddrsData)  {
>   ...... }

Thank you